# file not playing from Internal storage in Android

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

here is string to setDataSource

```
/data/data/com.player/app_player/file.mp3
```

getting E/Exception: setDataSource failed.

here is the code:

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse("/data/data/com.player/app_player/file.mp3"));
```

I stored that file using this code

```
getContext().getDir("player", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

which is same as /data/data/com.player/app_player

using content://data/data/com.player/app_player/file.mp3 did not work.

Comment: Give android permission : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: dear, I already set it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I solve it.

```
 String musicUrl = "";
 if (songSavedInDB()) {
            musicUrl = "here is any file path(Internal or external)"
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
            try {
                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(musicUrl);
                mPlayer.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());
                fileInputStream.close();
                mPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            musicUrl = "here is url";
            try {
                mPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(), Uri.parse(musicUrl));
                mPlayer.prepareAsync();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```